# PHP: Unlink doesn't work in 'deeper' folder

Tags: php, variables, unlink

I tried deleting the file from folder but it does not work...

I tried changing ' to " but it still does not work...

So I tried putting the exact value,
and it worked

```
    unlink('uploads/12/33.jpg');
```

This one deletes the image from gallery folder

```
unlink('gallery/'.$id.'.'.$ext);
unlink('gallery/thumbs/'.$id.'.'.$ext);
```

This one DOESN'T work.

```
unlink('uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_id.'.'.$image_ext);
unlink('uploads/thumbs/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_id.'.'.$image_ext);
```

I even tried changing the dot into a comma and it still didn't work :[

Comment: is the value of album_id correct?

Comment: Please output `'uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_id.'.'.$image_ext`, so you can see if this is the correct path.

Comment: Does your webserver has the rights to edit/delete files there?

Comment: Is the directory permission **777**?

Comment: @powtac I don't understand? I can delete when I put the exact address in unlink();

Comment: @CertaiN I am not sure. How do I check?

Comment: @Belzelga Launch your usual FTP client, and right-click the directory. This is the screen shot (on Japanese language pack, sorry xD) http://gyazo.com/4db2a8d40e2494e91636d4fbbdb377fa.png

Comment: @CertaiN I tried right clicking on the folder, and checked on the tabs but I did not find '777' permission, is that the 'read-only' check box? xD

Comment: Read, Write and Exec. Selecting all makes it 777. http://gyazo.com/27e9942ddcd334512c52289c8a4c1c47.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo "
    unlink('uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_id.'.'.$image_ext);
    unlink('uploads/thumbs/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_id.'.'.$image_ext);
";
```

and see if it shows you the correct syntax. Maybe you're still having an incorrect value or a missing slash or something.

Please paste your results here if this doesn't help you further.

Comment: Wow! I got tons of errors message, thank you nl-x .. I'm going to try and fix it @@

Comment: There was something wrong in my query, fixed and it is working now. Thanks again nl-x.